# Fitting a Gaussian to a probability distribution to find the standard deviation, in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, gaussian

[Plot of one distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCjCv.png)

I'm quite new to coding so please be patient.
I'm trying to model different probability distributions, and I would like to fit a Gaussian to each one and then find the standard deviation of the produced Gaussians, and then compare those std devs.

I'm unsure how to tell python to find the closest Gaussian to my curve, so any help is appreciated.

Here is my code so far, I tried to use curve_fit, but I really don't know how to, so I took it out, and I'm unsure how to define the Gaussian for the best fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import linalg, special, optimize, stats
from numpy import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

q = 4000
qA = np.arange(0.000001,q+1,1.0)
qB = q - qA
N = 2000
NA = 1000
NB = N - NA

ASA = (qA + NA -1)*np.log(qA + NA -1)-(qA*np.log(qA)) - (NA -1)*np.log(NA -1) #sterling approximate of SA/kb

ASB = (qB + NB -1)*np.log(qB + NB -1)-(qB*np.log(qB)) - (NB -1)*np.log(NB -1) #sterling approximate of SB/kb



TATA_list=[]
for i in range(1,len(qA)-1):
    
TATE = (qA[i+1] - qA[i-1]) / (ASA[i+1] - ASA[i-1])
TATA_list.append(TATE)                      

TBTA_list=[]
for i in range(1,len(qA)-1):
    
TBTE = (qB[i+1] - qB[i-1]) / (ASB[i+1] - ASB[i-1])
TBTA_list.append(TBTE)                      

AStot = (q + N -1)*np.log(q + N -1)-(q*np.log(q))-(N-1)*np.log(N-1)
Paprox = np.exp(ASA + ASB - AStot)
SUMPX = sum(Paprox[:-1])
NormPAprox = Paprox/SUMPX

plt.plot(qA/q, NormPAprox)
```

Comment: For clarification...are you fitting to a set of samples that you want to estimate the mean and variance of, or is it that you have an existing curve and you want to fit a Gaussian to it? If it's the former, what's the nature of each sample? In particular, is each sample a scalar or a vector, and does each sample have a label to identify which Gaussian/group it comes from?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 
I'm creating a probability distribution of Quantum Harmonic Oscillators in an Einstein solid at different sizes and differing numbers of QHO. The probability distribution I get from each sample is very close to a Gaussian curve. I'd like to know what the equation is for the Gaussian that most matches my curve. If that makes sense. I'd like to take different sample sizes and then compare the standard deviation/variance of each curve to comment on their differences.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to physically see the Gaussian fitted to the data but I would at least like to be able to retrieve the equation of the closest Gaussian to my data, just to obtain the sigma (σ) value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start by defining the curve to fit, providing an initial guess of the parameters. Then I run the fit and print out the results.

[image]

```
#Define the curve
def gaussian(x, mean, sigma, amplitude):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

#Drop NaNs
is_nan = np.isnan(NormPAprox)
is_valid = ~is_nan
print('Dropping', is_nan.sum(), 'NaNs')
x_vals = (qA / q)[is_valid]
y_vals = NormPAprox[is_valid]

#Initial guess for each parameter
# mean: x location of the peak
# std: std of x
# amplitude: amplitude of the peak
initial_guess = [x_vals[np.argmax(y_vals)], x_vals.std(), y_vals.max()]

#Get the fitted params
fit_params, fit_covariance = curve_fit(gaussian, x_vals, y_vals, p0=initial_guess)
print('Fitted mean, std, amplitude are:', fit_params.round(3))
print(' Variance of each estimate:', fit_covariance.diagonal().round(3))
```

Visualise the data and the fit (zoomed onto the peak):

```
#Plot original and estimated
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, linewidth=8, color='darkgreen', label='data')
plt.plot(x_vals, gaussian(x_vals, *fit_params), color='tab:orange', label='fitted')
plt.xlim(0.45, 0.55)
plt.title('Data and fit')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('qA/q')
plt.ylabel('NormPAprox')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you so so much for all your help :)

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I was able to help. You laid out a nice question and I enjoyed working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of fitting a Gaussian to some data using `sklearn`, with some visualisation. The data is just a list of measurements. You can fit more Gaussians, and they can be multidimensional.

[image]

Create some mock data and plot it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create some test data
np.random.seed(0)
measurements = np.random.randn(100)

#Plot the data
plt.scatter(range(0, len(measurements)), measurements, marker='s', c='tab:green', label='raw data')
plt.xlabel('sample number')
plt.ylabel('measurement')
plt.legend()
```

Fit model and report results:

```
#Fit Gaussian to the data
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

n_gaussians = 1
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_gaussians).fit(measurements.reshape(-1, 1))

#Print results
print(f'Fitted {n_gaussians} Gaussians to {len(measurements)} samples:')
for idx in range(n_gaussians):
    print(f' Gaussian {idx} mean:', gmm.means_.flatten().round(2))
    print(f' Gaussian {idx} var: ', gmm.covariances_.flatten().round(2))

#Overlay the fitted Gaussians
for idx in range(n_gaussians):
    mean = gmm.means_[idx]
    var = gmm.covariances_[idx]
    colour = plt.get_cmap('jet')((idx + 1)/ n_gaussians)
    plt.axhline(mean, c=colour, lw=2, ls='-', label=f'Gaussian {idx + 1} of {n_gaussians} (mean ± sd)')
    plt.vlines(idx, ymin=mean - var**0.5, ymax=mean + var**0.5, colors=colour)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1));
```

Comment: Salam. Thanks for your help, but I am still a little lost. I have edited the code you suggested to include my data labelled NormPAprox instead of the random data 'measurements' you used. But I am getting this error message 

Continued in next comment

Comment: ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
GaussianMixture does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively.

Comment: Alaykum assalam. No problem. It sounds like the data you have contains missing values i.e. NaN ("not  a number"). Models often require you to remove any NaNs from your data. What's the shape of your data? Try `print(my_data. shape)`. To remove NaNs, try: `data_valid = my_data[~numpy.isna(my_data)]`. If possible consider sharing a sample if your data, it might help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, my data does contain some non numerical values where there was a multiplication or division by 0 but I'm still getting the exact results I want and that I expect. I've uploaded in my original post, a screenshot of the data I'm getting out. It doesn't look very Gaussian on this scale but when zoomed in, its very close.

If you copy and paste my code and run it you might understand more what I mean but I do appreciate that you're trying very hard to assist me and I'm possibly not really understanding. But thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please see my newer answer.